# Is their a unique signature value for the state of of an sqlite3 DB (or table)?

Tags: database, sqlite, pysqlite

I was looking for some single value that tracked the writes to either the DB or an individual table in the DB.

I would like to say "This data was extracted at this time, from this DB, **in this state**"

I am not bothered about future updates recreating the data of the table, just information equivalent to a simple count of the number of writes  would do.

This would allow me to record the same info when I did other extracts from the DB and so could check to ensure consistency.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the database file's modified date and time from the file system.

Comment: Yep, that's what I have so far. I was searching if there were more. Thanks.